# Assign if not null operator

Tags: c#, null-coalescing-operator

Is there a shortcut to the following statement?

```
if(b!=null) a=b;
```

The best I can come up with is

```
a=b??a;
```

I want to assign `b` to `a` only if `b` is not `null`, otherwise I want to leave `a` unchanged.

The statement `a??=b;` is the opposite of what I want, equivalent to

```
if(a==null) a=b;
```

Comment: `a=b??a` seems concise enough for me - i don't think getting any shorter would provide any benefit at all. but to answer your question: no.

Comment: Isn't `a=b??a` already a shortcut?

Comment: The "shortcut" involves calling `a`'s setter and possibly getter regardless of `b`'s `null`ness. Ideally only the setter would be called, and only when `b` is actually null.

Comment: if your getters and setters have side-effects that could break something, then you shouldn't worry about whether or not they get called, but about fixing them.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann They could simply involve heavy IO which I would like to avoid, not necessarily side effects.

Comment: @programagor then i would say it's the task of the _getters and setters_ to check whether they have to do heavy lifting or not. just my two cents.